# Create a circular TableViewCell indicator like the Apple Mail app

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a circular indicator for my TableViewCell similar to the one in the Apple Mail app when the email is marked as unread.

[image: enter sdsdsdsd description]

I have the following code:

```
var Indicator = CAShapeLayer()
var IndicatorSize: CGFloat = 10

// standard blue color
let blueColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1)

// create circular CAShapeLayer
Indicator.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:IndicatorSize, height:IndicatorSize)
Indicator.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
Indicator.cornerRadius = Indicator.frame.size.width/2

// add as cell sublayer
cell.layer.addSublayer(Indicator)
```

While this seems to do the job, the circle doesn't feel as smooth as the one in the mail app, the corners look pixelated almost. I'm not sure if this is because I am using CAShapeLayer. I would like to know if there are better alternatives.

Also can I make this an object of the cell as opposed to just a layer so that I can call it using cell.Indicator?

Comment: @keithbhunter: It's not a troubleshooting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        self.tintColor.setFill()
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the time, `rect` will be OK. But one has to be aware it is "only" the rect that needs to be redrawn on screen, and is not necessarily identical to the whole dot rect. Anyway, details for this case.

Comment: That is a good point. And also this implementation assumes that the view will always be a perfect square and the dot will take up the whole view in order to make the dot. But this is enough code to get someone who wants it started.

Comment: I'm using UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle. Do I have to switch to a custom cell, create a UIView and associate it to the CircleView class or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you would need to make a custom table view cell and add the view to it.

Comment: Is there a way i can send a colour to update the CircleView based on an action? I have the following line but it doesn't seem to update:

        `cell.CircleIndicator.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()`

Answer (score 4):

Take a `UIView`. Subclass the `drawRect:` method and draw a `UIBezierPath` inside it.

Something like:

```
@implementation BlueCircleView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    // Assuming your view as the size of the dot you want.
    // Otherwise, simply pass another rect.
    UIBezierPath *round = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds];
    [round fill];
}

@end
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift. Answers should be in Swift, not Objective-C.